# How can we copy the jar file created in net beans project to some folder immediately after it stops building?

Tags: batch-file, netbeans-7

I wish to copy the executable jar file of a project immediately after its building completes to another folder location.

I do have a batch file to do that but, I wish to automate that in such a way that it is executed as and when the build finishes ..... !

How can I do it ?

Please help!

Comment: Can we make use of the build.xml file to customize the default location for the build ?
May be we can use the **-post-jar** tag or something like:
`<target name="-post-compile">`
`<obfuscate>`
`<fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>`
`</obfuscate>`
`</target>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by editing the Build.xml file one can try copying the file automatically to a desired location.
This is the Build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="testBuildXml" default="default" basedir=".">
<description>Builds, tests, and runs the project testBuildXml.</description>
<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
<property name="src"     value="<path-to-your-batch-file>"/>
<target name="**-post-jar**">
    <exec dir="${src}" executable="cmd.exe">
        <arg line="/c copy.bat"/>
    </exec>
</target>
</project>
```

"-post-jar" allows the batch to execute only after the jar building process is complete.
For further information you may check out this [web page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).

Comment: The solution is correct ... another thing that one can do is write the copy command in place of the batch filename i.e. 
`<arg line="/c copy ${ant.project.name}.jar ${destination}">`
${ant.project.name} gives the name of the project!